# Get biggest value from column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the biggest value from a column called amount, I tried using the `MAX` in the query but it did not get the largest one.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT MAX(amount) FROM games;
```

My table (`Amount` column):

```
+--------+
| amount |
+--------+
| 10     |
| 100    |
| 1      |
| 50     |
| 954    |
| 5      |
| 1000   |
| 90000  |
| 7      |
| 10     |
+--------+
```

Output:

```
+-------------+
| MAX(amount) |
+-------------+
| 954         |
+-------------+
```

Is there a reason why it is not getting the largest value possible?

Comment: Does `Amount`'s column data type is numeric ?

Comment: I'm guessing 'no'.

Comment: Ah, probably should of checked that. I didn't make the db so I just assumed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, the type is probably not right.

To see if it is the problem, you can convert directly using mysql:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(amount, SIGNED)) FROM games;
```

Comment: This is correct, thank you @Denis Leger, do you mind telling me what the CONVERT(amount, SIGNED) does exactly?

Comment: convert to a signed number, I guess, you can use google here.

Comment: you have all details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Answer (score 0):

it is because of field type in your database. if the type of column be a numeric type like int or etc , the MAX function works fine, otherwise you muse use other solutions.